# How to use a blogger xml template for a html website?

Tags: html, xml, blogs, blogger, blogspot

I have a blog and was trying to update my template. The blog is made with blogger. But one template attracted me very much. And I would like to use it as a template for a website I am currently building. The blogger templates are in xml format. How can I use it with my HTML site??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The fastes way would be(with the Browser Chrome):

1. Surf to the page
2. Right click somewhere on the page (on a free space)
3. Select the menu item *"Save as..."*
4. In the popup select a filename and the type **Complete, Webpage**

Like this you have the blog template as html file, with all needed scripts,css and image files. Finished!

> I recommend to clean the code. Remove unneeded scripts/css/images/...